# Using coTurn TCP allocations with DataChannel

Tags: tcp, webrtc, coturn, rtcdatachannel

I have configured a coturn server which I need to use with DataChannel for a chat app.

I am trying to reach a point where I can get the coturn server provide me with a tcp allocation.

I am using the standard call of `RTCPeerConnection` in JS client, providing the turn URI, username and credentials.

The transport I am providing in the URI params is TCP `?transport=tcp`.

With all this, I am always receiving a UDP allocation and the server logs ChannelBind requests (UDP based)

**Question:**

How can I achieve TCP allocations throught webRTC client, to guarantee proper data delivery of the chat app in case of using my relay server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC 6062, opening a TCP port on the TURN server is *not* supported by WebRTC. It is [optional in the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-transports-11#page-5) and nobody needs it since reliability is provided by SCTP.

TCP in the turn uri refers to the protocol between the client and the TURN server

Comment: see also [this discuss-webrtc thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/I9Ya78QdbSk/3vfU0ilcAgAJ)